# "My First BASS Application" BASS.NET application error

Tags: c#, bass

I am trying to create an application with audio from the BASS.NET Library, but I am getting a few errors on the "My First BASS Application" sample. I followed the given directions on http://bass.radio42.com/help/, but when I try running the pasted code, an error comes up on this line:

`if ( Bass.BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, IntPtr.Zero) )`

the error I recieve is:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Bass Test.exe`

I tried to follow all the directions, but for #4, instead of adding bass.dll, I added bass.net.dll thinking it was typo.

`4.Copy the 'bass.dll' to your executable directory (e.g. .\bin\Debug).`

The sample code is:

```
using System;
using Un4seen.Bass;

namespace MyFirstBass
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // init BASS using the default output device 
            if (Bass.BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // create a stream channel from a file 
                int stream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile("test.mp3", 0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_DEFAULT);
                if (stream != 0)
                {
                    // play the stream channel 
                    Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(stream, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    // error creating the stream 
                    Console.WriteLine("Stream error: {0}", Bass.BASS_ErrorGetCode());
                }

                // wait for a key 
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey(false);

                // free the stream 
                Bass.BASS_StreamFree(stream);
                // free BASS 
                Bass.BASS_Free();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am guessing that the code is fine but my computer's output device is whats causing the error.

Comment: Did you try to debug the application? Where does the error occur? The exception says that .NET couldn't create a type, probably because it couldn't locate all the dlls needed. If `bass.net.dll` is just a wrapper over `bass.dll` you'll need both dlls for your program to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BASS.NET is a thin wrapper over BASS, which means `bass.dll` is required. The link you provided explicitly warns:

> The native BASS libraries are NOT included and need to be downloaded separately - so make sure to place the BASS library and the needed add-on libraries to your project executable directory (e.g. place the bass.dll to your .\bin\Debug folder).

You don't need to copy `bass.net.dll` to the `Debug` folder yourself because you've already added it as a reference to your project.

Comment: Thank you,  I should really read the manual instead of skipping to the example.